# When running sys.stdout.write(), none is printed after what i want to print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing very simple code which takes input from stdin and prints output to stdout.

Input :

```
4    
3
```

Output(I am getting) :

```
1None    
1.333None
```

Expected Output :

```
1    
1.333
```

Can you help me out. Thanks in advance
Here is the code :

```
from __future__ import division
import sys

data = sys.stdin.readlines()

buffer = []

for d in data:    
       buffer.append(d)

a = buffer[0]    
b = buffer[1]    
p1 = (int(a)//int(b))    
q1 = (int(a)/int(b))    
m = str(p1)    
n = str(q1)  
print sys.stdout.write(m)    
sys.stdout.flush()    
print sys.stdout.write(n)
```

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`print sys.stdout.write(n)`. Pick one or the other.

`print` is printing the return value of `sys.stdout.write(n)` which is `None`.

Comment: That is, `print n` or `sys.stdout.write(n)`. The former is preferred, not least because `write` doesn't append a newline automatically. (Also, `print` don'ts require that `p1` or `q1` be explicitly converted to `str` objects first.)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Morgan and Chepner. It was so basic , i should have seen it. I get the correct answer now.

Comment: @Amol Glad I could help.